# Finding Minutes Between Years

Tags: python, datetime

can you please check my code? I think something is wrong somewhere.

```
import datetime
this_year = datetime.datetime.today().year


def age_in_minutes(b_year: int):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{this_year}', '%Y')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{b_year}', '%Y')
    age = (d1-d2).days * 24 * 60
    return f"{age:,}"


while True:
    birth_year = input("Enter you birth year: ")
    try:
        if int(birth_year) == this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif int(birth_year) > this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif len(birth_year) < 4 or len(birth_year) > 5:
            print("PLease enter a valid year...")
        elif int(birth_year) <= 1900:
            print("Please enter a year after 1900...")
        else:
            minutes_old = age_in_minutes(int(birth_year))
            print(f"You are {minutes_old} minutes old.")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter in a year format: ")
```

I'm tackling a challenge. It said if I enter 1930, I should get "**48,355,200**". But I'm getting "**48,388,320**". I'm new to Python.

Comment: It is because of leap years....  Your result of "48,388,320" is the more accurate result. `(388320-355200) / 24 / 60 = 23.0`   and `(2022-1930)/4 = 23.0`  there have been 23 leap year days since 1930.   in other words, there is nothing wrong with your result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this code
I found it somewhere in 2021 but I don't know the source

```
current_year = 2022
year = int(input("Please enter a year: "))

if year == current_year:
    print("There are 0 minutes from", year, "to present.")
elif year < current_year:
    print("There are", (current_year - year) * 525600, "minutes from", year, "to present.")
else:
    print("There are", (year - current_year) * 525600, "minutes from present to", year)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import datetime
this_year = datetime.datetime.today().year

print(this_year)
def age_in_minutes(b_year: int):
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{this_year}', '%Y')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(f'{b_year}', '%Y')
    age = (d1-d2).days * 24 * 60
    return f"{age:,}"


while True:
    birth_year = int(input("Enter you birth year: "))
    try:
        if birth_year == this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif birth_year > this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif len(str(birth_year)) < 4 or len(str(birth_year)) > 5:
            print("PLease enter a valid year...")
        elif birth_year <= 1900:
            print("Please enter a year after 1900...")
        else:
            minutes_old = age_in_minutes(birth_year)
            print(f"You are {minutes_old} minutes old.")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter in a year format: ")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter you birth year: 1930
You are 48,388,320 minutes old.
```

I don't do any exceptional but change your type casting, and it can give me a desire result.

Comment: or 2nd thing is that restart your kernel it can also give you a desire output. it may be a cache issue

Answer (score 0):

```
You haven't calculated leap year. You can follow this:
```

```
import datetime

this_year = datetime.datetime.today().year


def age_in_minutes(b_year: int):
    leap_year = 0
    non_leap_year = 0

    for year in range(b_year, this_year+1):
        if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
            leap_year += 1
        else:
            non_leap_year += 1
    
    leap_year_in_days = leap_year * 366
    non_leap_year_in_days = non_leap_year * 365
    age = (leap_year_in_days + non_leap_year_in_days) * 24 * 60
    return f"{age:,}"


while True:
    birth_year = input("Enter you birth year: ")
    try:
        if int(birth_year) == this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif int(birth_year) > this_year:
            print("Please enter year less than this year...")
        elif len(birth_year) < 4 or len(birth_year) > 5:
            print("PLease enter a valid year...")
        elif int(birth_year) <= 1900:
            print("Please enter a year after 1900...")
        else:
            minutes_old = age_in_minutes(int(birth_year))
            print(f"You are {minutes_old} minutes old.")
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter in a year format: ")
```